# How to get two Future composition done with atomic operation

Tags: vert.x

I have a Vert.x programming question.

Suppose I have an asynchronous method, inside this method, I will run the following piece of code, in this code, it will access database, first operation is to access resourceDao, second operation will access anotherDao. The first operation is done, then perform the second operation.

I hope the two steps can be done with atomic operation, that means, these two steps must be finished together without any interruption. I am wondering how to achieve it?

```
    Future<List<Resource>> resourceDaoFuture = resourceDao.getResource(id);
    resourceDaoFuture
        .onSuccess(
            res -> {

              Future<Integer> anotherFuture = anotherDao.update(another);
              anotherFuture
                  .onComplete(
                      res2 -> {...})
              });
```

Comment: It would help if you added the type of database that you're using.

Comment: We are using postgres

Comment: Does "vertx.executeBlocking" guarantee two Futures not be interrupted?

Comment: `executeBlocking` is only for blocking code.  It doesn't seem your case. I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Do you want to run the two operations one after the other or in parallel? What do you mean with atomic? What happens if update `getResource` fails?

Comment: Maybe you want to run them in parallel and get something returned if they both succeed?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that reliably can give you that type of guarantee is your database. Vert.x offers simplified access to transactions and you can read the documentation [here](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-pg-client/java/#_using_transactions). Using transactions you can make sure that the change either happens as a whole or doesn't happen at all.

Any other solution in your code will either be too complicated or not reliable.